# How to use FMResultSet Group By in FMDB iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I want to get grouped data from a table in SQLite. For example, the table is like below:

[image: table]

NSString *querySQL=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select * from %@ where company like '%@%@' and sepll||first_spell||phone||name like '%@%@%@' limit %d offset %d",TABLE_NAME,company,@"%",@"%",py,@"%",pageSize,(page-1)*pageSize];
FMResultSet *rs = [[dbManager getDatabase] executeQuery:querySQL];

My question is,after executeQuery,how can I group by id ascending about rs again?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Group By" clause. **GROUP BY** clause is used in collaboration with the **SELECT** statement to arrange identical data into groups.

```
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithString:@"SELECT Row_Name1, Row_Name2 FROM Table_Name where Row_Name1 like '%%?%%' or Row_Name2 like '%%?%%' group by Row_Name1, Row_Name2 order by Row_YouWantToGroup"];
 FMResultSet *rs = [theDatabase executeQuery:query];
```